# Delete photo in my application folder

Tags: c#, wpf

I have troubleshoot with delete picture in my application, I used foreach to delete file in folder.

I used Headless skype login in my applicaton with query contact name and contact's photos After login succeed, but I have problem when I closed my app ,I wanna delete all contact's photos in my app's folder .See the code to delete:

```cpp
var assemblyLocation = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
var applicationDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyLocation);
var imagesDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(applicationDirectory, "img");
var contact_photo = Directory.EnumerateFiles(imagesDirectory,
    "*.jpg",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
if (contact_photo != null)
{
   foreach (var photo in contact_photo)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(photo);

      File.Delete(photo);
   }
```

}

**Error Message:**

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\...\mypicture.jpg'
because it is being used by another process.
```

Help me please!

Comment: make sure you kill all the processes of the app because it still using pics you want to delete

Comment: Note that for normally installed applications you don't have write access to its folder.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1025446/988830

The file is used by another process and you have to make sure the process which has hold the file has released it. If it is not in your control then you need to you try catch block to avoid exception and you cannot do more than that.

```
try
{
    //Delete file
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, when I try to follow you the error show in console, But I don't know exactly, why I can't delete when I login corrected user name and password in Skype.

For me I'm not sure , but I think because of I using DispatcherTimer() in MainWindows to query contact loop in 5 seconds. So maybe problem with DsspatcherTimer when process delete that photo.

How do you think about this process? Problem with Skype runtime or DispactureTimer when I delete ?.

Any idea pleas !

Answer (score 0):

Before deleting the images, did you review your usage of those images?

Other parts of your WPF app may lock them when you don't notice,

[BitmapImage in WPF does lock file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430299/bitmapimage-in-wpf-does-lock-file)